# Why does my attempt at connecting a pushbutton to a lambda fail?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I have some issues while trying to use lambda expression to make connections between a pushbutton and a function I want to call when I click the button.

I am using Qt 5.6, with the compiler MinGW 4.9.2 (the default one). My code is the following :

In mainwindow.cpp :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    initBuildings();
    initPage();

    for (int i(0); i<buildings.size(); ++i) {
        connect(static_cast<QAbstractButton*>(widgetlist.at(i).at(2)), &QAbstractButton::clicked, [this, i]() {
            buildings.at(i).buy(amountMultiplier);});
    }
}

void MainWindow::initBuildings()
{
    Building b1 = Building("Building 1",100,1,200);
    Building b2 = Building("Building 2",1000,10,2000);
    buildings.append(b1);
    buildings.append(b2);
}

void MainWindow::initPage()
{
    for (int i(0); i<buildings.size(); i++) {
        QList<QWidget *> buttons;
        QLabel *namelabel = new QLabel(buildings.at(i).getName());
        QLabel *amountlabel = new QLabel;
        QPushButton *buybutton = new QPushButton(this);
        QPushButton *upgradebutton = new QPushButton(this);
        amountlabel->setFixedSize(50,40);
        buybutton->setFixedSize(100,40);
        upgradebutton->setFixedSize(100,40);
        buttons.append(namelabel);
        buttons.append(amountlabel);
        buttons.append(buybutton);
        buttons.append(upgradebutton);
        widgetlist.append(buttons);
    }
}
```

In mainwindow.h :

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QList>
#include <building.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void initBuildings();
    void initPage();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int amountMultiplier;
    QList<Building> buildings;
    QList<QList<QWidget*>> widgetlist;
};
```

And "Building" is a class I have created which does not inherit from another class. The function I want to use is a public funtion of this class:

```
void buy(int amount) const;
```

It doesn't compile and I get several errors :

- `no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QAbstractButton*, void (QAbstractButton::*)(bool), MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::<lambda()>)`
- `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QtPrivate::QEnableIf< false, QMetaObject::Connection>`
- `cannot convert '<lambda closure object>MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::< lambda()>{((MainWindow*)this), i}' (type 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::< lambda()>') to type 'const QObject*`

I tried to change the lambda capture list, or to change the way I get the value in the lists but it doesn't change anything and I don't figure what is the problem. Maybe I am wrong in the use of the lambda ?

Comment: What type is mylist?

Comment: Please show us declaration of `MainWindow::connect` function

Comment: @PcAF It's `QObject::connect`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4

Comment: This is **nowhere near** minimized code. Remember, everything that doesn't contribute to the error is noise. Please minimize this, put it into a single file, and make sure that *other than the one line with error*, it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. `buildings.at()` returns a `const Building &`, and the `buy` method is not const. You must index the buildings using `[]` instead.
2. The type returned from `widgetlist.at(i).at(2)` is definitely not `QPushButton*` - if it was, the code would compile. Even the error message indicates what the issue is:

> no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(**QWidget*** const&, void (**QAbstractButton::***)(bool), [...])

This compiles:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/lambda-list-37615204
#include <QtWidgets>

struct Building {
   void buy() {}
};

class Class : public QObject {
   QList<Building> m_buildings;
   QList<QList<QWidget*>> m_widgets;
public:
   Class() {
      for (int i = 0; i<m_buildings.size(); ++i)
         connect(static_cast<QAbstractButton*>(m_widgets.at(i).at(2)), &QAbstractButton::clicked, [=] {
            m_buildings[i].buy();
         });
   }
};

int main() {}
```

If you wish an extra measure of safety in face of programming errors on your part, replace the `static_cast` with a `qobject_cast`, it'll then abort if you cast a non-button instead of doing something possibly misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! But even with the changes you suggest there is the same error.
I made the static_cast but the result is the same. 
"no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QAbstractButton*, void (QAbstractButton::*)(bool), MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::<lambda()>)' "

Comment: @BricoMaster The code I show above works. That's your starting point. Paste it into a new project and ensure that it works there. Perhaps your compiler is broken? Perhaps you're doing something else? Please edit your question with **complete code that fails for you**. You should have posted something like in my answer above to begin with - it's your basic duty when asking a question on SO! It's a so-called minimization of your problem: everything irrelevant has been discarded. I had to guess at your code because your question is deficient.

Comment: I agree it can be difficult to guess an answer without the context. I have edited the question with the full code. With the error i get it seems like there is no function "connect" using lambda, even if the documentation say it is possible.

Comment: @BricoMaster You didn't read my example, and you got the fallout from not posting code earlier. The `buy` method in above was `const`: for a reason. You used `buildings.at(i)` returning `const Building &`, I had to assume that `buy` was const. Now that you've posted the code and `buy` is not const, it's obvious that you can't use `buildings.at`. You also get different errors, but you didn't bother telling us - and you didn't even attempt to understand the new error. *member function 'buy' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Building', but function is not marked const*

Answer (score -1):

According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), your lambda should accept a `bool` argument.

Comment: It doesn't have to. Functors/slots connected to a signal can ignore any number of trailing arguments, including all of them.